# Export selected rows datagridview to excel

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, datagridview, export-to-excel

i have to come out with a program to export selected rows datagridview to excel with the respective headers. I have done exporting the whole datagridview to excel, but now i want to do it with just the selected row. How can i do it?

here's my codes for exporting the whole datagridview to excel

private void GenerateExcel(DataTable table3, string excelSheetName)
        {

```
        string fileName = "TestingofDSI";
        //string currentDirectorypath = "C:\testingdsi";
        string currentDirectorypath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        string finalFileNameWithPath = string.Empty;

        fileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", fileName, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
        finalFileNameWithPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.xlsx", currentDirectorypath, fileName);


        var newFile = new FileInfo(finalFileNameWithPath);


        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
        {

            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(excelSheetName);


            if (table != null)
            {

                worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table3, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium2);
                //worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true, TableStyles.None);


                /*  package.Workbook.Properties.Title = @"This code is part of tutorials available at http://bytesofcode.hubpages.com";
                  package.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Bytes Of Code";
                  package.Workbook.Properties.Subject = @"Register here for more http://hubpages.com/_bytes/user/new/";*/


                package.Save();

                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("File name '{0}' generated successfully.", fileName)
                    , "File generated successfully!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {

                MessageBox.Show("please load data from database!");

   }


        }
    }
```

//code for binding data

```
   private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             GetData(" select * from jacksonpc.product;");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
     }

    private void GetData(string selectCommand)
      {
        try
        {
            // Specify a connection string. Replace the given value with a 
            // valid connection string for a Northwind SQL Server sample
            // database accessible to your system.
            String connectionString = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=1234";

            // Create a new data adapter based on the specified query.
            dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);

            // Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and
            // delete commands based on selectCommand. These are used to
            // update the database.
            MySqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

            // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
            table = new DataTable();
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            dataAdapter.Fill(table);
            bindingSource1.DataSource = table;



            /* table2 = new DataTable();
             table2.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
             dataAdapter.Fill(table2);
             bindingSource2.DataSource = table2;
             // Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.*/

                        dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Have you added any checkbox to select the row?

Comment: @Arshad do i have to do it? is there any other alternative way?

Comment: so how you will identify the selected rows, if user wants to select multiple rows

Comment: Do you want to work with single row

Comment: @Arshad i am able to identify by clicking on one of the button-like and it will highlight the entire row. I want to work with more than a one row.

Comment: then you have to add a checkbox

Comment: Can you share your code for binding data in the grid. apsx code

Comment: Ok.. are you using on windows application

Comment: @Arshad ahh..yes, kinda forget to mention it. sorry about that.

Comment: Ok.. i have it in asp.net.. let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `datagridview` `SelectionMode` property in constructor or `Form_Load`

`dataGridView1.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;` 
Then user will able to select multiple rows which the help of `CTRL` or `Shift`
 on you print method you have to create a `DataTable` with selected Rows:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    //Create a DataTable with same column name
    //fill each column like row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();              

}
```

Comment: how will this export the selected rows to excel?? i am able to select multiple but can't extract them into excel..

Comment: First you have to create a datatable then create new rows , add new rows to datatable...

Comment: After that call your print()  by passing newly created datatable

Comment: thanks for the help, i am able to do it now but i have new problem now...can i send u screen shot through your email or something?

Comment: You can discuss it here only.. attach details in the question it self